How can I lock screen orientation to portrait for tablet? (Android)
I want to lock screen orientation to portrait for tablet. and I implemented this in onCreate() method. However, the scree orientation  doesn't keep portrait and it's causing unnecessary flicker and re-creation of the activity. I don't know why. Please help me.
The dialog shows when dialogUiState is not null.
if (DeviceUtils.isTablet(this) && dialogUiState != null) {
    requestedOrientation = (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT)
   }

object DeviceUtils {
    @JvmStatic
    fun isTablet(context: Context): Boolean {
        val configuration = context.resources.configuration
        val screenLayoutSize = configuration.screenLayout and Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK

        return screenLayoutSize > Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL
    }
}

I want to know how to lock the screen orientaion to portrait for tablet.

Please elaborate on how it "doesn't work". What is your goal and what's going wrong?

I can actually rotate the screen which I don't want. I want to lock the screen orientation to portrait. What should I set to android:configChanges = and android:screenOrientation=? My goal is that the screen orientation keeps portrait  even though I rotate the screen.

You should use SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT to ignore sensor.
According to the docs, SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT can still use the sensor:

Would like to have the screen in portrait orientation, but can use the sensor to change which direction the screen is facing.


Thank you for the comment. I changed to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT. However, the screen orientation doesn't keep portrait when I rotate the screen on tablet. Any other things I should fix?

I actually solved this problem by changeing SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT. The problem of unnecessary flicker and re-creation of the activity was probably caused by emulator. After restart the emulator, it has solved. Thank you.
